# what if your pole is also a zero for contour integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

for example $$f(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{x-1}$$

That's just a general example. But Im confused on what that would imply.

Comment: There's no such thing as a pole which is also a zero. What point do you have in mind for your example?

Comment: If you have a pole and a zero of the same order, then this will be a removable singularity. More carefully said, if $f(z)$ has a zero of order $k$ (or more!) at $a$ and $g(z)$ has a zero of order $k$ at $a$, then $f(z)/g(z)$ has a removable singularity at $a$.

Comment: You have a removable singularity by expanding the log around 1.